# How to create a ByteBuffer from Bitmap using grayscale pixel value?

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I am trying to use a `tflite` model in my android app. The problem arises when I have to create a ByteBuffer out of the Bitmap and use it as Input to the model.

**Problem:** Bitmap is ARGB_8888 (32 bit) whereas I need (8 bit) grayscale image.

Method to convert Bitmap to ByteBuffer:

```
mImgData = ByteBuffer
                .allocateDirect(4 * 28 * 28 * 1);

private void convertBitmapToByteBuffer(Bitmap bitmap) throws NullPointerException {
    if (mImgData == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("Error: ByteBuffer not initialized.");
    }

    mImgData.rewind();

    for (int i = 0; i < DIM_IMG_SIZE_WIDTH; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < DIM_IMG_SIZE_HEIGHT; j++) {
            int pixelIntensity = bitmap.getPixel(i, j);
            unpackPixel(pixelIntensity, i, j);
            Log.d(TAG, String.format("convertBitmapToByteBuffer: %d -> %f", pixelIntensity, convertToGrayScale(pixelIntensity)));
            mImgData.putFloat(convertToGrayScale(pixelIntensity));
        }
    }

}

private float convertToGrayScale(int color) {
    return (((color >> 16) & 0xFF) + ((color >> 8) & 0xFF) + (color & 0xFF)) / 3.0f / 255.0f;
}
```

However, all the pixel values are either -1 or -16777216. Note that that unpackPixel method mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41332416/2231031) doesn't work, since all values have the same int value anyway. (Posted with changes below for reference.)

```
private void unpackPixel(int pixel, int row, int col) {
    short red,green,blue;
    red = (short) ((pixel >> 16) & 0xFF);
    green = (short) ((pixel >> 8) & 0xFF);
    blue = (short) ((pixel >> 0) & 0xFF);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call `Color.red()` or green/blue on the pixel value and it will return the gray intensity. Then just put it in the byte buffer using `putFloat()`. Also getting all pixel values in a single array using `bitmap.getPixels()` is comparatively faster than `bitmap.getPixel(i, j)`. Here's how I am doing it to load grayscale images in my tflite model:

```
private ByteBuffer getByteBuffer(Bitmap bitmap){
    int width = bitmap.getWidth();
    int height = bitmap.getHeight();
    ByteBuffer mImgData = ByteBuffer
            .allocateDirect(4 * width * height);
    mImgData.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    int[] pixels = new int[width*height];
    bitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
    for (int pixel : pixels) {
        mImgData.putFloat((float) Color.red(pixel));
    }
    return mImgData;
}
```

If you need normalized values just divide by 255:

```
float value = (float) Color.red(pixel)/255.0f;
mImgData.putFloat(value);
```

You can then use this in your interpreter as:

```
ByteBuffer input = getByteBuffer(bitmap);
tflite.run(input, outputValue);
```

Hope this helps people looking for this in the future!